# JQuery UI Dialog not scrolling horizontally - text adjusted to dialog size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scrollbar, jquery-ui-dialog

See fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/wn2q5s3c/3/

Text is being forced to the next line at the dialog width. Look at 'Fourth Level' text and 'Fifth Level' text. I would like it to stay in the same line and need to view the text that runs out of the width boundary with a scrollbar.

Doing a quick hack just to test, if I throw in some long text with no spaces then it does scroll how I want it to but the text is still being forced to next line http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/nvmbsdcy/2/
I have tried setting the overflow and scroll styling on the div but didn't fix it. I might not be doing it correctly.

Javascript

```
jQuery( "#tree" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: true,
       title: "Backup Subpaths",
       resizable: false,
       width: 300,
       height: 400,
       modal: true
});
```

HTML

```
    <div id="tree" style=" overflow:scroll">
        <ul>
            <li><a>First Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>First Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Second Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Third Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Third Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Fourth Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Fourth Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Fifth Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>First Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Another Level</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Another Level2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
                <li><a>Second Level</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some css:

```
 .ui-widget-content a {
     clear: both;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

I have updated the fiddle:
please check:
http://jsfiddle.net/wn2q5s3c/4/

Comment: I didn't realize the problem went all the way down to the <a>. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this really helped